# Detect Filled circle accurately and assign unique id?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect a filled circle and get the value of that circle for example first circle have value 1 and carry one. I have attached the image below the circle will fill with a black or blue pen. The size of the circle is very small so basically what I am trying is that I just want the specific filled circle value and then to save it into the database.
Right now its values are 1 or 2, but sometimes its value is 1 or sometimes have some world like APPLE, etc....
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gu2Go.png

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import math
img = cv2.imread("small.jpg",0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
circles =cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,60,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
counter=0
correctC=[]
xC=[]
yC=[]
for i in circles[0,:]: 
 #cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
 #cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),2)
 cv2.putText(cimg,str(i[0])+","+str(i[1])+","+str(i[2]),(i[0],i[1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.3,(255,0,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
 correctC.append((i[0],i[1],i[2]))
 xC.append(i[0])
 yC.append(i[1])
 counter+=1

print "Circle Count is : " + str(counter)

xCS=sorted(xC)
yCS=sorted(yC)
xS=sorted(correctC, key=lambda correctC:correctC[0])

q1=sorted(xS[:4],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q2=sorted(xS[4:8],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q3=sorted(xS[8:12],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q4=sorted(xS[12:16],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q5=sorted(xS[16:20],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q6=sorted(xS[20:24],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q7=sorted(xS[24:28],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q8=sorted(xS[28:32],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])
q9=sorted(xS[32:],key=lambda correctC: correctC[1])

sortedTmp=[q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8,q9]
sorted=[]

for i in sortedTmp:
  for j in i:
    sorted.append(j)

for i in range(36):
 cv2.putText(cimg,str(i),(sorted[i][0],sorted[i][1]), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1,(255,0,0),3,cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution to detect and filter the filled circle is this:

1. **Threshold** the image via Otsu
2. Get **Connected Components**
3. Search for the target blobs based on **aspect ratio** and the **difference between the blob's bounding box and the blob's area** - The difference should be relatively small.

Let's see the code:

```
# Imports:
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Image path:
fileName = "gu2Go.png"
path = "D://opencvImages//"

# Read image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(path + fileName)

# To Grayscale:
grayscaleImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold:
_, binaryImage = cv2.threshold(grayscaleImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Get Connected Components:
output = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(binaryImage, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
(numLabels, labels, stats, centroids) = output
```

Now, let's loop through all connected components (the blobs) and filter based on aspect ratio (the circles seem to have the same height and width, and their aspect ratio should be close to `1.0`) and difference between the blob's bounding box and the blob's area. Imagine you have the bounding rectangle of the filled circles. If you subtract the area actual area of the blob, as they are roughly of the same proportions, the difference should be small. Certainly smaller than the difference between an  unfilled circle's bounding rectangle and its area:

```
# Store target bounding boxes here:
boundingBoxes = []

# Loop through connected components:
for i in range(1, numLabels):

    # Get blob properties:
    x = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_LEFT]
    y = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_TOP]
    w = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_WIDTH]
    h = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_HEIGHT]
    blobArea = stats[i, cv2.CC_STAT_AREA]
    (cX, cY) = centroids[i]

    # Get bounding box area:
    boxArea = w * h

    # Compute area difference
    areaDifference = boxArea - blobArea
    # Compute aspect ratio:
    aRatio = w / h

    # Set blob filter:
    minAreaDifference = 800
    minAspectRatio = 0.9
    maxAspectRatio = 1.1

    # Default color is red:
    color = (0, 0, 255)

    if areaDifference < minAreaDifference:
        if aRatio > minAspectRatio and aRatio < maxAspectRatio:
            # Got target blob
            # Color is now blue:
            color = (255, 0, 0)
            # Store bounding box in list:
            boundingBoxes.append((x, y, w, h))

    # Draw rectangle:
    cv2.rectangle(inputImage, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 3)

# Show the results of the filter:
cv2.imshow("Bounding Rects", inputImage)
```

The result should color the filled circles with a blue bounding rectangle and the rest with a red one. Note that I've stored the target blobs bounding rectangles in a list called `boundingBoxes`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for your answer much appreciated. But the problem is when I put the full image in OpenCV, my image was cut from the bottom means the full image is not set on the whole canvas and I want to open a full image in whole canvas and then detect the filled box. I am attaching the my result screenshot below as well as my template.

My result screenshot:
[my result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SK2A.jpg)

What I am trying to I trying to resize this image in high quality and fit it into the canvas and then try to detect the filled boxes and then give the unique ID to every detect box to get the value. So my scenario is that I will give each unique id some value and then for example if ID one box is filled then give that box to one value.

My original template: [Original template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5fws.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).