# Finding location of irregularly painted circles in an image

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image

Consider the following image:

[image]

From this image, I need to get the coordinates of the black painted circles. I thought about methods of blob detection. But given the irregularity of the painting, I am not sure those would be a reliable methods.

Could you please help me?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71151831/detect-filled-circle-accurately-and-assign-unique-id

Comment: I would just get the circles from HoughCircles. Then once I knew where the circles were one could determine if filled or not by the average color within the circle.

Comment: Thanks, @fmw42 and stateMachine. Hough circles is an excellent idea! I am wondering, motivated by curiosity, what would be the solution in case the image had no circles.

Comment: Solution to what when there are no circles?

Comment: Exactly, @fmw42! Maybe blob detection?

Comment: If there are no circle, what are your features that you are looking for?

Comment: Suppose the image only contains those manually painted "blobs" and nothing else (no circles, no printed straight lines). How could we find the location of the each "blob", @fmw42? Thanks!

Comment: If there were no lines and no circles, you could invert the image so you have white blobs (where there are scribbles), maybe do some morohology to close the holes between scriibled lines, maybe some blurring, then find the peaks.

Comment: Thanks, @MarkSetchell, for your suggestions, which appear very promising to me! I am going to study the morphological operations for selecting the most appropriate.

Comment: Look at the 3 statements here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74360428/2836621 that start with `grey=...`, `SE=...` and `mask` but use MORPH_ DILATE and a bigger structuring element.

Comment: You could invert and do morphology to close up the markings. Then get contours and filter on area for example or circularity.  Alternately after the morphology, in place of contours, you could do blob detection with cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats() filtering on size and shape/circularity.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @fmw42, for your suggestions, which also appear very promising! I am going to try those.